# Issue when opening Electron application on Mac - "the git command requires command line developer tools."

Tags: node.js, git, macos, electron, electron-builder

**Solved** The 'systeminformation' package runs several shell commands - git being one of them. I modified the source to prevent those commands from running, as I didn't need them. The app runs fine without any prompts now

**Original question** I have built my Electron application on Windows and mac using Electron builder. The `dmg` file installs correctly and runs correctly, but each time I open the application, I get the same prompt:

> "the git command requires command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?"

I have tried on multiple macs. They all show the same message when I open the application. I have looked everywhere for references to a git command - I only found the `"hosted-git-info"` package. Any idea what could be causing this issue ?

The npm packages being used in the app are:

```
"ajv": "^6.5.1",
"crypto": "^1.0.1",
"crypto2": "^2.0.0",
"electron-json-storage": "^4.1.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"lokijs": "^1.5.5",
"node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"popper.js": "^1.14.3",
"replace-in-file": "^3.4.0",
"systeminformation": "^3.42.0"
```

I had included `ajv` and `popper.js` only because it kept saying that these dependencies were required and had to be installed manually. I have also created a new project using `electron-quick-start`, included these dependencies and got no prompt message. Something in the code is triggering this most likely?

See a screenshot of the prompt:

[image: See a screenshot of the prompt]

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/ ? Else it could be found on Apple website.

Comment: The application runs fine by itself even without installing those tools. I'm trying to figure out why that message is showing - I want to get rid of it

Comment: Do you open each time the dmg?

Comment: No - the dmg is only run once to install the app. After that, I open it from Launchpad each time. The app opens and runs correctly, but I get this prompt each time I open it.

Comment: There is a git command bring run from somewhere - I can't seem to locate it. I don't know if it has something to do with electron builder

Comment: I also tried it on a system where those tools are installed. The error doesn't show. But i don't want my users to be prompted with this each time they open the app. It functions fine without those tools - i need to understand what is causing that message to appear

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an error. It's an installer prompt for command line tools.

Hey, the package which you highlighted, hosted-git-info is for identify and transform various git hosts URLs between protocols. It also can tell you what the URL is for the raw path for the particular file for direct access without git. Your installer is trying to touch that package (or it's being used) and it finds that command line tools are not installed on the machine where you are trying to install.

```
hosted-git-info on GitHub is here: https://github.com/npm/hosted-git-info
```

As you mentioned in comments when you try to install your DMG on a machine which has already installed, the error (or I should say installer prompt) didn't occur.

Just check if you are not using that package. If you are not using then remove it. Else, it's good to have command-line-tools installed on mac always. (Again, it's not an error. Its an installer prompt)

Comment: Thanks for that information ! So should i run "npm uninstall hosted-git-info" and try again ? I don't want the user to get this prompt, as they will most probably never use the command line tools for any of their usual work

Comment: If you know that you dont want hosted-git-info package. Then go ahead.

Comment: please note, this isn't an INSTALLER prompt. It is a prompt that pops up everytime i open the APPLICATION. Even if i ignore the prompt, the application works fine, but i don't want the prompt to pop up each time, is all

Comment: Yes, i understand your point here. Its not an installer propmt for you or ur app. But Im talking as in Mac OS perspective where your app runs. The package in ur app hosted-git-info has dependency on git command which has to he installed via above promt which you are telling.

Comment: I ran "npm uninstall hosted-git-info" and then packaged the app using electron builder. Still getting the same prompt on Mac OS. The app runs fine, but the prompt shows up each time the app is started. So it seems like it isn't an issue with "hosted-git-info" but something else that is trying to run a git command

Comment: Ho! That's strange. I thought there's nothing apart from hosted git info is using in your app. Can you edit your questions and post which npm packages you are using in your app??

Comment: Solved! The 'systeminformation' package runs several shell commands - git being one of them. I modified the source to prevent those commands from running, as I didn't need them. The app runs fine without any prompts now

Comment: would appreciate if you can hep me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182226/electron-builder-is-not-bundling-the-python-files

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this fix in "systeminformation"?